# Pandas groupby then rolling mean

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the code below in an attempt to group by a column value, then run a cumulative sum and moving average on ordered data for that group only:

```
#this works OK
df['csum'] = df.sort_values(['name','day_time','delta_minutes'],ascending=True).groupby(['name']) ['value'].cumsum()

#throws error
df['rolling'] = df.sort_values(['name','day_time','delta_minutes'],ascending=True).groupby(['name'])['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Original dataframe:

```
    name    value   delta_minutes   day_time    
0   MAC000039   0.069   0   2012-10-13  
1   MAC000039   0.054   30  2012-10-13  
2   MAC000039   0.085   60  2012-10-13  
3   MAC000040   0.082   0   2012-10-12  
4   MAC000040   0.053   30  2012-10-12  
5   MAC000040   0.075   60  2012-10-12  
6   MAC000040   0.195   90  2012-10-12  
7   MAC000039   0.098   0   2012-10-12  
8   MAC000039   0.055   30  2012-10-12  
9   MAC000039   0.054   60  2012-10-12  
10  MAC000039   0.099   90  2012-10-12
```

Expected output

```
    name    value   delta_minutes   day_time  csum rolling
0   MAC000039   0.069   0   2012-10-13  0.375 ..
1   MAC000039   0.054   30  2012-10-13  0.429 ..
2   MAC000039   0.085   60  2012-10-13  0.514 ..
```

I get the following error when attempting the rolling mean

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: So you are able to get Csum column but not the "Rolling" column. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: In your Expected output, the values have changes (Day, Time, value). Is this supposed to happen?
Additionally, if you want help with the Rolling column, I think it might be helpful to give enough sample data to get non-nul entries

Comment: I have updated my code - actually the csum worked when I tested it on a fraction of my data, issue is just with the rolling mean

Comment: What is your expected output for `rolling`?

Comment: @IanThompson Nan in first row for each unique name then average of previous and current value as per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `df.sort_values(['name','day_time','delta_minutes'],ascending=True).groupby(['name'])['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()` has a `MultiIndex`. To fix it, reset the `'name'` index and drop it.

```
import pandas as pd

"""
name    value   delta_minutes   day_time    
0   MAC000039   0.069   0   2012-10-13  
1   MAC000039   0.054   30  2012-10-13  
2   MAC000039   0.085   60  2012-10-13  
3   MAC000040   0.082   0   2012-10-12  
4   MAC000040   0.053   30  2012-10-12  
5   MAC000040   0.075   60  2012-10-12  
6   MAC000040   0.195   90  2012-10-12  
7   MAC000039   0.098   0   2012-10-12  
8   MAC000039   0.055   30  2012-10-12  
9   MAC000039   0.054   60  2012-10-12  
10  MAC000039   0.099   90  2012-10-12
"""

df = pd.read_clipboard()

# sorting before adding columns
df.sort_values([
    'name',
    'day_time',
    'delta_minutes'
], inplace = True)

# cumulative sum grouped on name
df['csum'] = df.groupby('name').value.cumsum()

# reset index `name` and drop it
df['rolling'] = df.groupby('name').value.rolling(2).mean().reset_index(level = 'name', drop = True)

print(df)

         name  value  delta_minutes    day_time   csum  rolling
7   MAC000039  0.098              0  2012-10-12  0.098      NaN
8   MAC000039  0.055             30  2012-10-12  0.153   0.0765
9   MAC000039  0.054             60  2012-10-12  0.207   0.0545
10  MAC000039  0.099             90  2012-10-12  0.306   0.0765
0   MAC000039  0.069              0  2012-10-13  0.375   0.0840
1   MAC000039  0.054             30  2012-10-13  0.429   0.0615
2   MAC000039  0.085             60  2012-10-13  0.514   0.0695
3   MAC000040  0.082              0  2012-10-12  0.082      NaN
4   MAC000040  0.053             30  2012-10-12  0.135   0.0675
5   MAC000040  0.075             60  2012-10-12  0.210   0.0640
6   MAC000040  0.195             90  2012-10-12  0.405   0.1350
```